# Loop through HTML with Selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How can I iterate throuah all the list-items of  `<ol class="daily-weather-list__intervals"`?

[image]

I want to go though everey sub-item, that is

```
<li class="daily-weather-list-item" id="DayliWatherListItem0"
<li class="daily-weather-list-item" id="DayliWatherListItem1"
...
<li class="daily-weather-list-item" id="DayliWatherListItem8"
```

and collect the data stored in the classes

```
'temperature min-max-temperature__max temperature--warm')
'temperature min-max-temperature__min temperature--warm')
```

as shown below:

[image]

Is there a way to do this using Selenium Webdriver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `find_elements` instead :

```
for li_values in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "ol.daily-weather-list__intervals li"):
    print(li_values.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this works:

```
weatherList = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//div[@class='daily-weather-list-item']")
for e in weatherList:
    minMaxTemp = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//span[@class='min-max-temperature']/span").text
    warmTemp = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//span[contains(@class,'temperature__separator')]/span").text
```